# bitmap save jpeg failled but png is ok because of the comments property

Tags: c#, bitmap, save

**Question Description:**

when I save the bitmap to a JPEG file with JPEG format mode, a Gdi exception was thrown. But when i save it with a PNG format mode, it can be saved successfully.

**Quick Recreate:**

1. Please save the images to .jpg file from the broswer. click here: [IncorrectImage](http://www.screencast.com/t/JlMn7SRr), [CorrectImage](http://www.screencast.com/t/TVJvAQCp).(actually, in our application, we request the image on the fly and then save the image to JPEG.)
2. using the below code to see the exception:

   `string newFile = @"D:\Temp\newImage.jpg";
   var newBitmap = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Temp\IncorrectImage.jpg");
   newBitmap.Save(newFile,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

**What i found:**

after a deep investigation, i found out the root of the issue is from **the Comments property** of the orginal image.  when i delete the the property value, the error disappears. Besides, after i just copy the value of the comments value of the image to notepad and then paste back, the image can be saved into a new image with the upper code and the size of the image even is larger!
[image]

So, i guess the comments property might includes some sensitive or incorrect charector when saving to a jpeg file. Would guys can give our some insights on those comments?

thanks in advanced.

**More try:**

I try the below code:

```
        //foreach (var item in newBitmap.PropertyItems)
        //{
        //    if (item.Id == 37510)
        //    {
        //        item.Value = null;
        //        item.Len = 0;
        //    }
        //}
        newBitmap.RemovePropertyItem(37510);
        newBitmap.Save(newFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

if I remove the property item, then the newimage can be saved successfully. However, if I just set its value null like the comment out codes, the exception is still thrown.

**Please help me:**

1. Why the image size is larger(orginal size is 48k, after cut and paste back it's about 78k) when I just clear the comments and then paste the same value back. Is it possible a bug?
2. Why the image can be saved successfully after I clear the comments and then paste the same value back? is it the Clipboard filter some invalid charactors?
3. Why the image still cann't be saved even I have set the comments property value is null? but if I remove the property, it can work, like the before i try?

Hope you can help me find out the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the root of the issue from MSDN
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83b24aa5-511f-47cd-856a-4fbbb5688ddf/bitmap-save-jpeg-failled-but-png-is-ok-because-of-the-comments-property

It appears that the original comment uses ASCII encoding but GDI+ auto converts it to Unicode. The comment is already large and converting to Unicode doubles its size and it exceeds the maximum size of the EXIF block (64 kbytes).